# Mapping out a third list based on two list values

Tags: python, list

I have two lists one is a subject list, it can vary from 2 to 4 subjects at max. Second list is reporting list which provides information,whether we need a report for the subject.

Possible values for reporting list are:

- All_Subjects which means we require report for all subjects.
- No_Subject which means we dont require report for any subject
- Lastly the format, SubjectName_(All|NO)_Report which means if for a particular subject we want a report or not.
  -subject_list = ["Subject", "Chemistry", "Physics" , "Mathematics" , "Bio"]  #sequence always remains same.
- reporting_list can be ["All_Subjects", "No_Subjects", "Chemistry_No_Report","Chemistry_All_Report"] #sequence does not matter

Function report_required returns a list whether we want a report or not, and returns a list. If list has all "None" values it means no report required.

For example: I have:

```
reporting_list = ["Chemistry_No_Report", "Mathematics_All_Report] 
subject_list   = ["Subject", "Chemistry", "Physics" , "Mathematics"]
```

My subject_list always starts with a value Subject, which I ignore when returning mapped values
my return value should be `["No", None, "Yes"]`

My current function below works, is there a more efficient way of mapping out a third list based on two list values.

```
def reportRequired( reporting_list , subject_list):

    report_list = [None]*4


    for value in reporting_list:
                # subject_list starts with a header value "Subject", thats why iterating from index 1
                if value.startswith("All"):
                   for idx in range(1, len(subject_list)):
                        report_list[idx-1] = "Yes"

                if value.startswith("No"):
                    for idx in range(1, len(subject_list)):
                        report_list[idx-1] = "No"


                if value.split("_")[1].lower() == "no":
                    for idx in range(1, len(subject_list)):
                        if value.split("_")[0].strip() == subject_list[idx]:
                            report_list[idx-1] = "No"

                if value.split("_")[1].lower() == "all":
                    for idx in range(1, len(subject_list)):
                        if value.split("_")[0].strip() == subject_list[idx]:
                            report_list[idx-1] = "Yes"
      return report_list
```

Comment: report_req_list is never changed - so you didn't test this code, did you?

Comment: @Sebastian I think he didn't even compile it. He just threw the question here so someone can write the code for him. He's a smart one.

Comment: @Sebastian this code does work, i modified my variable names from the original code, in the process i got a typo. I am just looking at a more efficient way of designing this. Currently, the code is doing its required job. Just looking forward to improve my skills in writing better code.

Comment: In your example, the return value has 3 elements. Should be 4? And you claim that "sequence does not matter". But the "All" and "No" commands modify all values of the report_list, so the last one wins.

Comment: sequence of reporting list does not matter, but of subject_list and final report list does mattter. Report list should map to subject list. If reporting list starts with "All" and "No" it modifies all values of list, that is correct, and okay. It is taken care of in another part of the code. If All_Report is in reporting list, and "Chemistry_No_Report" is also in reporting list, All_Report takes precedence.

Comment: But if you want All_Report to take precedence, why don't you immediately return ['Yes']*4? Because if you don't, and Chemistry_No_Report comes later, that will take precedence.

Comment: Sebastian, yes I can do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary that maps a subject name to an index and use that to access an element of the report_list. This way, you avoid quadratic complexity of the 3rd and 4rth case.

For the 1st and 2nd case: prepare a list filled with Yes-es and a list filled with No-s. Then you can use them, regardless how often that case appears in the reporting_list.
Note: You can use ['Yes']*4, as you already do in the initialization of the report_list.

Overall complexity is "almost" linear (assuming O(1) dictionary access...)

Edit: If a subject can appear multiple times in the subject list, this doesn't work.
But you can build a dictionary in which you store the answer for every subject, and in the second phase, walk through the subject list and output the answer for every subject.

Comment: thanks, Sebastaian. I cannot use "Yes" and "No" for my 1st and 2nd case as my subject_list can vary in size. It is okay to have a extra None value that I am initializing with, then a "yes" or "no".